# What am I told I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links. Yet I have - 67 Points -

Tags: bug, answers

As you can see I have well over 10 reputation.... Yet **ONLY** when I try to post more than 2 pictures I get the following messages upon submission of my answers...

[image: Need 10 Points]

AND this is at the bottom of the page.
[image]

... >>> Testing to add 3rd image after the fact here >>> [image]

Comment: If you edit this question and add another picture does SE still spit out the error message? Also did this happen on more then one day? (What day?) I'm trying to figure out what happened here that SE did not want your pictures.

Comment: This happened this afternoon.... I have been able to whip out answers with less than 3 pics since.

Comment: @David♦     It just worked by adding it during an edit.

Answer (score 3):

These messages both came from May 4 when you attempted to ask [Why is Bump causing blackout of material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78982/why-is-bump-causing-blackout-of-material) and self-answer. If you look at [your reputation history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/37991/christopher-tiller?tab=reputation&sort=time) you can see you hadn't yet earned any reputation. (Well, you had, but the post was deleted, which meant you lost it.)

Looking at the logs, I don't see any time the system blocked you from posting since May 4 except a time you failed the CAPTCHA. (Hey, it happens to the best of us.)

After a rocky start, it looks like you've righted the ship and it should be clear sailing for you now.

Comment: ♦ I got these exact messages this afternoon, when I had over 50 points.

Comment: @ChristopherTiller: Those errors don't show up in the logs. Is it possible you have a UserScript installed? Otherwise, it's difficult to see how you got those warnings. If you still have the problem, we'll need the details of your OS and browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well you *were* [answer banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/278094). That is why you got the *"We are no longer accepting answers from this account"* message. Looking at your answers, I *think* it was probably deleting [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/77553/2217) that pushed you over the edge of SE's low quality filter.

As of right now your account does not have any bans against it, so read the linked meta post, keep your questions and answers of good quality, and don't delete everything just because it got down voted.

(I'm still looking in to, and waiting to hear back from SE about why you had the "you need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links" message.)

Comment: ♦  Thank you. I erased that one because it really offered no help to anyone as far as I could tell.... As you are saying I have no bans, yet this afternoon I was blocked & screen shot both of those images as I was answering a question.  I am thinking there is a glitch in here somewhere. I may not know Blender all that well.... But I am not new to code.

Comment: As per your suggestion I was just able to add a 3rd image during an edit. I will clean my cache out and hope it was on my end.